Reading a dataset with different values and arrays from HDF5 using C++
I am trying to read data from an HDF5 file using C++, and I am only able to use the H5Cpp library.
The general structure resembles this:
DATASET "ds" {
 DATATYPE H5T_COMPOUND {

     H5T_IEEE_F64LE "var1";

     H5T_ARRAY { \[3\] H5T_IEEE_F64LE } "var2";

     H5T_ARRAY { \[3\]\[3\] H5T_IEEE_F64LE } "var3";

 }

 DATASPACE SIMPLE { ( 10000 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED )

}
I can't figure out how to read the dataset due to the fact that it has a float, and array of floats, and a 2d array of floats.
I tried creating a structure with the same form using insertMember for each different variable/type, but I'm getting read errors. Is anyone aware of a straightforward approach to this?
